# How to get the checked radio button. shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do i get the value of the selected radio button
below is my html

```
<select id="pages>
   <option>option here</option>
   <option>option here</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="line_spacing" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line Spacing</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="radio line_spacing_radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Double Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Double Spacing
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Single Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Single Spacing
        </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an event that works great and am able to retrieve the selected value in real time but my man issue is getting the value of the radio button when am performing another event i have tried multiple selectors none seems to work for me what could be the issues.

Below is the the event that works when i toggle the radios.

```
$('input[type=radio][name=line_spacing]').change(function() {

   line_spacing_data = this.value;


});
```

the above will give the selected radio correctly but when i try

```
var line_spacing = $('input[type=radio][name=line_spacing]:checked').val();
```

or

```
var line_spacing = $('input[name="line_spacing"]:checked').val();
```

or

```
var line_spacing2 = $('[name="line_spacing"]:checked').value;
```

all i get is undefined this is because i want to get the value the use it in another action.

this is how i want to get my checked radio

```
$('#pages').on('change', function(){

    var line_spacing2 = $('[name="line_spacing"]:checked').value;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably executing that line too soon, i.e. before any radio is selected. Your radios are unchecked, so the queries don't select any element. Calling `.val()` on an empty collection: `undefined`.

You need to run the query *in your event handler* whenever you want to get *the currently checked radio*'s value, if any!

Comment: I have updated my question showing how i want to do it

Comment: @dannjoroge jQuery collection do not have `.value` property. You should use the `.val` method instead.

Comment: For sure i was executing it too soon

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i was executing my line too soon 
below is how i was doing it before

```
var line_spacing2 = $('[name="line_spacing"]:checked').val;
$('#pages').on('change', function(){
  alert(line_spacing2);    /// this was throwing the error undefined
});
```

as advised by @undefined

here is how am doing it now and getting the response i want

```
$('#pages').on('change', function(){

  var line_spacing2 = $("input[type=radio][name=line_spacing]:checked").val();
  alert(line_spacing2); //this is OK
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made you one example, it will print on the console the value of the checked radio button every 2 seconds (if no one is checked, it will print undefined, like you will see when the program begins).

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        var line_spacing = $('input[type="radio"][name="line_spacing"]:checked').val();
        console.log(line_spacing);
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="line_spacing" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line Spacing</label>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="radio line_spacing_radio">

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Double Spacing" />
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Double Spacing
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Single Spacing" />
            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Single Spacing
        </label>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're checking the value of your input before it has actually been selected. The code below works perfectly fine. If there is no radio button that matches the `:checked` selector then that selector will return `undefined`.

```js
function checkvalue() {
    alert($("input[type=radio][name=line_spacing]:checked").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="line_spacing" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line Spacing</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="radio line_spacing_radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Double Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Double Spacing
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Single Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Single Spacing
        </label>
       </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="checkvalue()" >Check value</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct ! You have undefined value because you didn't made any choice ! You have to manage this case (see my code), or simply make one of the radio buttons selected by default :

```js
$("#ok").on("click", function(){
  var line_spacing = $('input[name=line_spacing]:checked').val();
  if (line_spacing == null)
   alert('Please make selection !')
  else
   alert(line_spacing)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="line_spacing" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line Spacing</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="radio line_spacing_radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Double Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Double Spacing
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Single Spacing" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Single Spacing
        </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="ok" value="Get choice">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add onchange=function() to the radio tag.

Here is an example. You can try it in CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/Benyomin_Walters/pen/Pyjabq).

```
<script>
    function changeSpacing(value) {

        document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = value;

    }
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="line_spacing" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line Spacing</label>
   <div class="col-sm-7">
     <div class="radio line_spacing_radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Double Spacing" onchange="changeSpacing(this.value)" />
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Double Spacing
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="line_spacing" value="Single Spacing" onchange="changeSpacing(this.value)"/>
          <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></span>
            Single Spacing
        </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="selection">nothing selected</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your selector looks wrong. You should use

```
var checkbox = $('[name="line_spacing"]');
var checkbox_value = checkbox.value;
```

The `[name="line_spacing"]:checked` selector will select your checkbox, only if it is checked. The selector is making your read to `.value` inaccesible.

Comment: I hope this satisfies your standards... Or this will get a 3rd downvote |: